# If condition never met and hence my bars in a simple bar chart are always blue, while I want them to be red for values below a certain number

Tags: javascript, html, function, d3.js, charts

I have been trying this code to create a bar chart with given data. It works but it never returns a red, rather returns blue always. I have tried putting b[i]>0, still only blue bars. The function wit parameter b is executed for sure and I have tried (b,i) too.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src = "https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg height = "250px" width="500px"></svg>
    <script>
        var b = [5,9,6,4,3]; 
        var x = 100; 
        const height = 250; 
        for(var i=0; i<b.length;i++)
        {
            var svg = d3.select("svg").data(b).append("rect").attr("x",x)
           .attr("y",height - (b[i]*20))
           .attr("width",20).attr("height", b[i]*20).attr("fill", function(b){
                if(b[i]<6) //This if condition never gets checked and hence doesn't work
                {
                    return "red";
                }
                else
                {
                    return "blue"; //This executes
                }
            })
            x = x + 25; //Increment for the position of next bar
        }
     </script>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make a shadow variable b, as an argument of the callback, so it is not an array, but the item of it. Since you are using cycle for drawing each point separately, you could avoid use callback for this.
So instead of

```js
.attr("fill", function(b) { ... })
```

you need to write this

```
.attr("fill", b[i] < 6 ? "red" : "blue")
```

Btw, d3 js can iterate points for you:

```
<script>
    var b = [5, 9, 6, 4, 3];
    var xOffset = 100;
    const height = 250;

    var svg = d3.select("svg")
        .selectAll('rect')
        .data(b)
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr("x", (d, i) => xOffset + 25 * i)
        .attr("y", d => height - d * 20)
        .attr("width", 20)
        .attr("height", d => d * 20)
        .attr("fill", d => d < 6 ? "red" : "blue");
</script>
```